# Как обойти два массива параллельно?

Tags: ruby

Есть модели `Item` (товар), `Property` (свойство), и `PropertyItem` (соединительная таблица с атрибутами `item_id`, `property_id` и `value`)

Есть два объекта `Property`

```
<Property:0x00000000064c4a18 id: 3, name: "SSD">,
<Property:0x00000000064c4888 id: 4, name: "Процессор">
```

Есть два значения для этих свойств

```
["256Гб", "Core i5"]
```

Полученных при парсинге таблицы

Нужно в SSD (`Property id: 3`) записать **256Гб**, а в Процессор (`Property id: 4`) - **Core i5**. 
Т.е.

```
<PropertyItem:0x00000000064c4a18 id: 4623, item_id: 68, property_id: 3, value: "256Гб">,
<PropertyItem:0x00000000064c4888 id: 4622, item_id: 67, property_id: 4, value: "Core i5">
```

Например делаю так:

```
properties.each do |property| # в блок передаю объект класса Property (property)
    property_names.each do |name| # в property_names находится массив ["256Гб", "Core i5"]
        PropertyItem.create_with(value: name).find_or_create_by(item_id: item.id, property_id: property.id)
    end            
end
```

При это понятно что первый раз объект сохранится правильно, а во второй раз просто найдет объект, который создался до этого, потому что `property` переданный в блок тот же самый.

Comment: Эк у вас всё запутано. Во-первых, у вас не **вложенность**, а **соответствие**, этот цикл будет пытаться последовательно создать 4 `PropertyItem`'а, просто 2 из них пропустит как уже существующие по паре `item_id`+`property_id`. Во-вторых, `property_names` должно быть `property_values`, т. к. у вас хранятся там именно значения свойств, а не названия.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для обработки таких данных в <s>швейцарском ноже</s> [`Enumerable` есть метод `zip`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-zip), применяемый, на основе вашего последнего примера, следующим образом:

```
properties.zip(property_names) do |property, name|
  PropertyItem.create_with(value: name)
              .find_or_create_by(item_id: item.id, property_id: property.id)
end
```

В отличие от вашего способа, здесь блок будет вызван не 4 раза, а только 2, и хак с `find_or_create_by`, пропускающий запись значения в несоответствующее ему свойство (весьма оригинальный, хоть и странный и неэффективный способ) не потребуется.

---

*(Примечание к исходной редакции вопроса) То, что у вас, это не вложенность, а **порядковое соответствие** между двумя массивами: любому элементу с индексом `N` первого массива соответствует элемент с таким же индексом `N` из второго.*